# Record user's inputs from html and save in it file/DB

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to record the user inputs from html page, later I can use the input to test the page using testing Api.

I need to get all the form controls like button, textbox , check box and etc...
then save the name/ID of the control and value in file or table.

so that I can use the name/Id and value to test the page. In this way I have planned to automate the testing.

Please let me know, How do I record the control name and value from html. Is there is any browser plugin for this. please share your idea.

Thannks

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to serialize form data with **jQuery** :

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
});
```

Comment: Thanks Majid, Let me me try it out.